# C++/ How to instantiate an object based off user input

Tags: c++

For example if the user inputs a string "modem", is there a way to instantiate an object of class Modem.

Or is there a much simpler way of doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::string strText = "modem";
CBase *pBase = nullptr;
if(strText == "modem")
    pBase = new CDervied1;
else
    pBase = new CDervied2;
```

Answer (score 1):

In this example, I would use the Factory Pattern. See http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html

Answer (score 0):

A way to use `std::map` would be to add a static member function `create` to each subclass, like

```
class CDerived1 : public CBase {
public:
    static CBase* create() {
        return new CDerived1;
    }
}
```

And have a map of the function pointers:

```
typedef CBase*(create_function_t*)();
std::map<std::string, create_function_t > mapping = {
    {"modem", &CDerived1::create},
    ....
}

...

CBase* pBase = mapping[strText]();
```

Comment: For more generality, the factory functions don't have to be static members like that: they could be any function with the right signature. For even greater generality, you could use `std::function` instead.